# How to override productcollection.php from vendor?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, overrides, core

I have to override the file `ProductCollection.php` from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product`.

I have read many posts but still not getting to override the file.

Can anyone please explain it to me step by step?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In order to override

First create `di.xml` in your module `Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
    <plugin name="product-collection-sorting" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\Collection" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Create `Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\Collection.php` and pasted below code in your file:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product;

class Collection
{

    //do stuff here like override functions
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I have tried it but it's not working. Please guide me

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overriding the Product collection you can create a plugin on the public function of ProductCollection.php. It is a recommended way for doing any modification to core files.